# Keep job running after script stopped by CTRL+C

Tags: python, terminate

I'm running an example script here:

```
os.system("xterm &")
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

python opens xterm, but after I stop the script by CTRL+C the xterm closes.

if I run

```
os.system("xterm &")
```

only, script ends and terminal keeps open.

How do I do than even if I terminate script by CTRL+C, the terminal will keep open?